# Error While Running spark on Eclipse

Tags: scala, apache-spark

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY2QH.png)

Getting this error while running spark with scala can anyone suggest how do i solve this issue.

Comment: can you share your pom.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not created this as a maven project. What you need to do is delete this project from eclipse. then :

File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Project -> Select your folder.

This would load your project and include maven dependencies and you would not face errors.